# What exactly causes the reputation bubble (counter) in the top bar to reset?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, notifications, top-bar

Sometimes when I view my reputation changes, the reputation notification bubble in the top bar disappears and starts counting from zero again. How can I avoid this? In other words, when exactly does this happen?

Informally, I *think* I have established that

1. Clicking on the reputation bubble in the top bar resets it. This is trivial and obvious.
2. Going to my profile and viewing the reputation tab *sometimes* seems to reset the counter in the reputation bubble. Is this a bug, or are there some specific conditions which I have not discovered?

It seems that there is a separate delta for the profile's reputation; in the profile itself, I see a green bubble with a number which seems to represent my reputation changes since the previous time I reviewed it.

For example, here is my meta profile; I seem to have earned 3.6k reputation on this site since the previous time I reviewed the reputation changes via my profile; in the meantime, the global reputation change bubble in the upper right corner shows +592 net reputation accrued since the bubble was last reset, almost certainly from viewing reputation changes on Stack Overflow via my profile on my desktop browser:

[image: My meta.SE profile]

Informally, viewing reputation changes via my profile from my phone never seems to reset the bubble in the top bar; and viewing reputation changes via my profile in my desktop browser only sometimes resets it.

Trying to avoid having the notification bubble start over from zero is just a stupid game I play, but I would like for the mechanism which controls this to be documented.

Answer (score 4):

You see the "unread" reputation change in the bubble. Once you check it, of course, it is no longer such.

As you correctly inferred, this is what happens:

- You get a positive reputation change (negative reputation change do not trigger a bubble when they happen without a positive one, but they are still listed)
- The bubble shows up, counting the total reputation change since the last time you opened the notification list

For example, if you first got a downvote and then an upvote since the last time you checked the bubble, you would see:

- an empty bubble
- downvote ==> no bubble, but you will see the rep going down 2 while being in the site where you got the downvote
- upvote ==> bubble shows +8

The only way I have found for not resetting it is to never open it.

By the way, you can play the same game with the reputation counter in the left bar of your profile.

Comment: This doesn't explain under which circumstances the counter resets if I never click it open, which is really the crux of my question.

Comment: @tripleee only a dev can tell, sadly. From own experience, like the author of this answer, only clicking the bubble resets it, and it was reset globally for all users once or twice following some bug that resulted in overall recalc for all users. The profile sidebar rep bubble is independent as far as I can tell, but then again, maybe it's not really so, only dev can confirm.